# Python: PyGame: как остановить цикл While?

Tags: python, gui, pygame, while

Я хотел сделать так, чтобы при нажатии **ЛКМ** запускался цикл `while`, а при отпускании цикл останавливался, но цикл продолжает работать при отпущенной **ЛКМ**.

Также я пробовал: выводить **1**, если ЛКМ нажата и **0** - если нет. 
Вне цикла `while stop == 1:` все работало. Внутри пишет **1**, даже если ЛКМ не нажата.

Вопрос: Почему цикл не останавливается и как это исправить?

Программа:

```
import pygame



pygame.init()
p = 2
y = True
s = True
click = 0
x = 640
y = 480
height = 100
width = 100
display = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y))

def main():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255, 255, 255), (x//2-(width//2) ,y-height, height, width))
def click():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 255), (x//2-(width//2) ,y-height, height, width))
    
  
while s:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        main()
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        x_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
        print(x_mouse, y_mouse)
        x_square1 = x//2-(width//2) 
        x_square2 = x//2-(width//2) + width
        y_square1 = y-height 
        y_square2 = (y-height) + height
     
        if x_mouse >= x_square1 and x_mouse <= x_square2 and y_mouse >= y_square1 and y_mouse <= y_square2:
            stop = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
            click()
            t = True
            print('окраска произошла ') 
            while stop == 1:
                stop = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
                print('ЛКМ нажата')
                while  t == True:
                    print("цикл вычисления координат")   
                    t = False
                    x_square_dim = x_mouse - x_square1 
                    y_square_dim = y_mouse - y_square1
                    pygame.display.update() 
                print ("цикл отображения")
                
                pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 255), (x_mouse - x_square_dim, y_mouse - y_square_dim, height, width)) 
                pygame.display.update()
        else: 
             main()


        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            s = False     
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, не совсем понял, что вы поправили в коде?

Comment: А, понял! Но ошибка была не в этих трёх кавычках, так как эти кавычки случайно попали в код про оформлении вопроса)

Comment: Да ясно, я просто форматирование подправил. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
p = 2
y = True
s = True
click = 0
x = 640
y = 480
height = 100
width = 100
display = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y))

def main():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255, 255, 255), (x//2-(width//2) ,y-height, height, width))
def click():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 255), (x//2-(width//2) ,y-height, height, width))
    
  
while s:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        main()
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        x_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
        print(x_mouse, y_mouse)
        x_square1 = x//2-(width//2) 
        x_square2 = x//2-(width//2) + width
        y_square1 = y-height 
        y_square2 = (y-height) + height
     
        if x_mouse >= x_square1 and x_mouse <= x_square2 and y_mouse >= y_square1 and y_mouse <= y_square2:
            stop = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
            click()
            t = True
            print('окраска произошла ') 
            while stop:                                                  # == 1:
#                stop = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]                    # ---
                print('ЛКМ нажата')
                while  t:                                                # == True:
                    print("цикл вычисления координат")   
                    t = False
                    x_square_dim = x_mouse - x_square1 
                    y_square_dim = y_mouse - y_square1
                    pygame.display.update() 
                print ("цикл отображения")
                
                pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 255), (x_mouse - x_square_dim, y_mouse - y_square_dim, height, width)) 
                pygame.display.update()

# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv         
                event_list = pygame.event.get()
                for event in event_list:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: 
                        print(f'MOUSEBUTTONUP отжата !!!')                
                stop = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                
        else: 
             main()


        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            s = False     
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.

Comment: @Cessna пожалуйста